# Recognize subscriber objects by their Delegate object in C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have this object:

```
public class ImageQueueMgr
{
    public delegate void OnImageQueueFilledHandler(int imageQueueId);
    public event OnImageQueueFilledHandler OnImageQueueFilled;

    ReleaseImageQueue(Object obj);

    Delegate[] delegateList;
}
```

Other objects can subscribe to this objects event `OnImageQueueFilled`. I want that all objects stay subscribed but I also want to keep track of the subscribers that called `ReleaseImageQueue(Object obj)` so that I can make some cleanup after all subscribers have called:
`ReleaseImageQueue(this)`

For know I can have the list of subscribers like this:

```
delegateList = OnImageQueueFilled?.GetInvocationList();
```

So my question is, how can I find the delegate that corresponds to the object that called `ReleaseImageQueue(this)`?

Comment: If I subscribe my method `myMethod` to your event (`+= myMethod`) I can unsubscribe from it with `-= myMethod`). Take a look at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: @dcg Yes I know, but I don't want to unsubscribe, because I have one thread generating a vector of images and several threads processing them. When all processing threads are finished they signal the image vector for memory cleanup.

Comment: What about another event to notify subscribers all processing is done so they can unsubscribe?

Comment: Its the subscribers that are processing the images, each one with different algorithms, I need to notify the ImageQueue manager that all subscribers are done.

Comment: I just edited the question so its more easy to understand, meanwhile I found a good solution that I'm willing to share but can't because the question was closed... :-| please open it so I can post the solution, which I think is rather interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this using `delegate->Target->Equals`, its in managed C++ but the C# equivalent is pretty straightforward:

```
List<Delegate^>^ m_delegateList = gcnew List<Delegate^>();

void SetDelegateList(cli::array<Delegate^>^ delegateList)
{
    // Convert cli::array to List
    for each (Delegate^ delegate in delegateList)
    {
        m_delegateList->Add(delegate);
    }
}

bool RemoveDelegateFromList(System::Object^ obj)
{
    Delegate^ delegateToRemove = nullptr;

    for each (Delegate^ delegate in m_delegateList)
    {
        if (delegate->Target->Equals(obj))
        {
            delegateToRemove = delegate;
            exit;
        }
    }

    if (delegateToRemove != nullptr)
    {
        m_delegateList->Remove(delegateToRemove);

        Debug::Print("removed delegate");
    }

    // If the list of delegates is empty then all of them are done with this image queue
    if (m_delegateList->Count == 0)
    {
        m_mreWaitDone->Set();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got the problem correctly you want to remove delegate's from a copy of the actual event invocation list, you don't want to unsubscribe from the actual event. In this case, you can just copy the invocation list in another event with `Delegate.Combine()` method. Consider the following code:

```
 public class ImageQueueMgr
{
    public delegate void OnImageQueueFilledHandler(int imageQueueId);
    public event OnImageQueueFilledHandler OnImageQueueFilled;

    private OnImageQueueFilledHandler _onImageQueueFilledCopy;
    private void CopyEventInvocationList()
    {
        var delegateList = OnImageQueueFilled.GetInvocationList();
        _onImageQueueFilledCopy = (OnImageQueueFilledHandler)Delegate.Combine(delegateList);
    }

    public void NotifyFinish(OnImageQueueFilledHandler finishedHandler)
    {
        _onImageQueueFilledCopy -= finishedHandler;
    }

}
```

This way subscribers can easily delete delegates from the invocation list without actually unsubscribing. See the following use example:

```
    public static class Program
    {
        private static ImageQueueMgr _queueManager = new ImageQueueMgr();
        
        public static void ImageQueuedEventProcessor(int imageQueueId)
        {
            //some code here
            //........
            
            //unsubscribe when done
            _queueManager.NotifyFinish(ImageQueuedEventProcessor);
        }
        
        public static void ImageQueuedEventProcessor2(int imageQueueId)
        {
            //some code here
            //........
            
            //unsubscribe when done
            _queueManager.NotifyFinish(ImageQueuedEventProcessor2);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            _queueManager.OnImageQueueFilled += ImageQueuedEventProcessor;
            _queueManager.OnImageQueueFilled += ImageQueuedEventProcessor2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you got it right, just send a notification back without unsubscribe or double dependency.